# using 'reform' gem with nested routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

i want to use 'reform' gem to create object with nested attribute. i have models:

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lunch_set
end

class Side < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lunch_set
end

class LunchSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant
  belongs_to :day
  has_one :dish
  has_many :sides
end
```

lunchset controller 'new' method:

```
def new
    @lunch_set = @restaurant.lunch_sets.build
    @form = LunchSetForm.new(dish: Dish.new, side: Side.new)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @lunch_set }
    end
end
```

routes file:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :restaurants do
      resources :lunch_sets
      resources :days do
        resources :lunch_sets
      end
    end
  end
```

and LunchSetForm

```
class LunchSetForm < Reform:Form
    include DSL
    include Reform::Form::ActiveRecord

    property :name, on: :dish
    property :name, on: :side
end
```

my question is how to construct views/admin/lunch_sets/_form.html , especially considering those routes? when i tried

```
= simple_form_for @form do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :name

  .actions
    = f.submit "Save"
```

but it gives me error

```
undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass
```

and points into line

```
= simple_form_for @form do |f|
```

Comment: Did you get this issue fixed?

Answer (score 2):

form_for (and in turn, simple_form_for) expect the form object to have ActiveModel methods like model_name to figure out how to name your form and its inputs and to resolve the form's action url. You're close to getting it right by including Reform::Form::ActiveRecord, but there are a couple more things you need to do:

```
require 'reform/rails'

class LunchSetForm < Reform:Form
  include DSL
  include Reform::Form::ActiveRecord

  property :name, on: :dish
  property :name, on: :side

  model :dish
end
```

The `model :dish` line tells Reform that you want the form's 'main model' to be the Dish instance. This means that it will make your form respond to the methods that ActiveModel usually provides for normal Rails models using the 'main model' to provide the values for those methods. Your form input names will look like `dish[name]` etc and it will post to your dishes_url. You can set your `model` to anything you like, but an instance whatever you choose needs to be passed into the form constructor.